# How to getText of value entered in `TextField` widget in flutter integration test

Tags: flutter, flutter-integration-test

In flutter integration test, i want to get the text entered in `TextField` widget.

Here is the development code looks like:

[image]

,

**Here is the integration test code I written to get the text of it**

[image]

,

**Its printing the hole widget tree data, but i want to only get the value entered in `TextField`**

Any helps highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Just use a Test controller.
Create your TextEditingController as a global variable in your State class and set it into your TextField widget.

```
final TextEditingController monthlyHousingPayment = TextEditingController();



 @override
  void dispose() {
    // Clean up the controller when the widget is disposed.
    monthlyHousingPayment.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

    TextField(
  controller: emailController,
  obscureText: true,
  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    border: InputBorder.none,
    hintText: 'PLEASE ENTER YOUR EMAIL',
    hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
  ),
)
```

you can get the value using :

```
monthlyHousingPayment.text
```